# Denodo query to search by column using wildcard character

Tags: sql, denodo

I am trying to figure out how to manage a view to return resultset based on the wildcard search
If it oracle, I will use
`select * from employee_table where employee_name = '%Jac%'`
This will return a resultset where the employee names are 
`Jack
Jackson
Jacob`

I have a denodo url which returns the json based on the employee_name and I have to enter the complete employee name to get the result,

`http://localhost.com:9090/xyz/employee_view/views/employee_view?employee_name=%Jack%&$format=json`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is... however, you probably need single quotes in your url: `http://localhost.com:9090/xyz/employee_view/views/employee_view?employee_name='%Jack%'&$format=json`.  You can also try this syntax: `http://localhost.com:9090/xyz/employee_view/views/employee_view?$filter=employee_name like '%Jack%'&$format=json` .  URL encoded it will look like this: `http://localhost.com:9090/xyz/employee_view/views/employee_view?$filter=employee_name%20like%20%27%25Jack%25%27&$format=json`

Answer (score 1):

I just test this and it works:

```
http://hostname:9090/server/databasename/resource_name/views/view_name?$filter=name%20like%20%27%Jac%%27&$format=json
```

I'm not sure how to get it working without the $filter parameter, though.

Comment: Have you published the web service?  You can also use the built-in web services that are auto-published: http://hostname:9090/denodo-restfulws/databasename...